# How do I sell items at the auction house in WOW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I can't seem to find the option to sell items at the auction house, only buy them. How do I do this?

Update: **Have included the answer** visually **below**  for posterity.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no "Sell Orders" in World of Warcraft, however you can put your own item up for auction by using the "Auction" tab with the auction house window open.

If you want other players to buy out your item right away, set a "buyout" price. The "starting" price is mandatory, but can be set to the same value as the buyout price to discourage bidding.

Comment: It should be noted that people usually won't buy items without a buyout unless the bid is very low, and even then, usually to repost the item at a more reasonable price and make some profit.

Answer (score -2):

You can press auction, and it will allow you to put your item for auction.